# Changing iText list bullet to a black spot

Tags: java, list, itext

I want to create an unordered list using iText. However, I don't want the default bullet to be dash, but a black spot (look to the spot right to your reputation marking your medals - something like that, but black). I don't know if iText has this already implemented (I couldn't find it), or do I have to do it manually.

The problem is, if I have to do it manually, since there are no black spots on a keyboard, I'd have to insert an image as the ListSymbol, but the `setListSymbol` method only accepts `Chunk` or `String` as an argument...

What do I do?

Comment: You probably want to use style sheets. http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your own question. You can use a Chunk as list symbol. If you want to use a custom image (e.g. one that visualizes a black spot), you can wrap such an image inside a Chunk. If you don't want to draw such an image yourself, you could look for a font that has one (Webdings? Wingdings?) and use a Chunk with a character from that font.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example, this char is the bullet of unorder list in HTML.

```
 List list = new List(List.UNORDERED);
 list.setListSymbol("•");

 list.add(new ListItem("list 1");
 list.add(new ListItem("list 2"));
 list.add(new ListItem("list 3"));
```