# ITextSharp SetListSymbol as an image

Tags: c#, list, pdf-generation, itext

I know that `SetListSymbol` (from the `ITextSharp` library) expects a `string` as a parameter, but is it possible to use an image/icon somehow? If so, how?

Comment: From my research, it appears you can wrap an image in a "Chunk". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325645/changing-itext-list-bullet-to-a-black-spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ListWithImageAsBullet](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ListWithImageAsBullet) example. It takes the image of a light bulb and uses it as if it were a bullet like this: [list_with_image_bullet.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/list_with_image_bullet.pdf)

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG);
image.scaleAbsolute(12, 12);
image.setScaleToFitHeight(false);
List list = new List();
list.setListSymbol(new Chunk(Image.getInstance(image), 0, 0));
list.add("Hello World");
list.add("This is a list item with a lot of text. It will certainly take more than one line. This shows that the list item is indented and that the image is used as bullet.");
list.add("This is a test");
document.add(list);
```